# XPath for Dynamic ID using Chrome Autoclick Extension

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I am using a google chrome autoclick extension to automate the process of making on online reservation.
I'm stuck to get the Xpath of a button (for a dropdown menu), as the button has a dynamic ID/name... it changes everytime the page is refreshed or upon login.

The dropdown menu button is to select a date, as shown in the screenshot attached further below.

1. Below is the Xpath of the dropdown button :
   `//*@id="5w2imT08i9uNPm/x35RIp2m8nKDYx+SmrtQM6uCMVnmGMPYcxHzCZALFb8rdGUV1hiepClvWbHByeqjKwryZziHEG4F/w2UfhY2F8mlxosw="]`
2. Below is the Element of the dropdown button :
   `\<select name="5w2imT08i9uNPm/x35RIp2m8nKDYx+SmrtQM6uCMVnmGMPYcxHzCZALFb8rdGUV1hiepClvWbHByeqjKwryZziHEG4F/w2UfhY2F8mlxosw=" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'5w2imT08i9uNPm/x35RIp2m8nKDYx+SmrtQM6uCMVnmGMPYcxHzCZALFb8rdGUV1hiepClvWbHByeqjKwryZziHEG4F/w2UfhY2F8mlxosw=\',\'\')', 0)" id="5w2imT08i9uNPm/x35RIp2m8nKDYx+SmrtQM6uCMVnmGMPYcxHzCZALFb8rdGUV1hiepClvWbHByeqjKwryZziHEG4F/w2UfhY2F8mlxosw=" style="width:328px;">`
   `<option value="2020/11/27">Fri, 27 Nov, 2020</option>`
   `<option value="2020/11/28">Sat, 28 Nov, 2020</option>`
   `<option selected="selected" value="2020/11/29">Sun, 29 Nov, 2020</option>`
   `<option value="2020/11/30">Mon, 30 Nov, 2020</option>`
   `<option value="2020/12/01">Tue, 01 Dec, 2020</option>`
   `<option value="2020/12/02">Wed, 02 Dec, 2020</option>`
   `<option value="2020/12/03">Thu, 03 Dec, 2020</option>`
   `<select>\`

Can anyone please help me to figure out what Xpath should I use to automate the click of this button?

I have tried to use the FullXPath but does not work.

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkYiM.jpg)

Comment: What is this drop down about add the screen shot

Comment: @AzmirFaizal Update the question with the outerHTML/parent elements of the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably anchor your XPATH to the label 'Date'. Find that and then find the select element.
If you show the html portion that represents your screenshot I could make an objective suggestion.